# Apache Kafka partitioning for user activity logging

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

How can I partition a topic which is collecting messages/records of user activity logging?

Such that when customer-care department gets a call from a particular user, they can quickly get the activity log for that specific user.

Partitioning on user-id is not an option as we are talking about 2 million users.

And since in case of Kafka we can't do something like JMS selectors, we will have to write Kafka consumer to read all the messages from a particular topic partition.

I am aware of the basic strategy where we create, let's say 50 partitions and then do something like

partition# = hash(user-id) mod 50

Considering a huge number of records, I am concerned about the # of records we will have to process to filter the records for a particular user.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why don't you store these events in ELK or something like that? Wouldn't it be easier to use for guys from Customer Care Dept.? What is the retention policy you choose for this topic?

Comment: The retention policy is 1 day. At the close of business hour, we push this into the relational database. ELK may not be a good choice as future analytics has to run on the same data set. And retention policy would be bumped up.

Comment: I see ELK, and especially Kibana as a nice browser of events. You could for example use TTL on documents (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/mapping-ttl-field.html) and CC Dept will be satisfied. I see no reason (well... maybe "just" cost and potential complexity) why ELK cannot be used together with a future analytics solution. That's why Kafka is so powerful.

Comment: If it goes to a RDBMS anyway, how about Kafka Connect JDBC? Point being - Kafka is just a channel for data transfer here, not for searching by the call center.